# Erlang eDoc: Function doc comments don't show up in output

Tags: erlang

I'm trying climbing the learning curve toward Erlang best practices; just now integrating eDoc into my workflow.

This works for me:

```
%%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%%% @author Lloyd R. Prentice
%%% @copyright 2011 Lloyd R. Prentice
%%% @doc Yada yada
%%%      ...
%%% @end
%%% --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Everything shows up in the docs as I'd expect.

But this doesn't:

```
%% Return a list of reserved item types
item_types() ->
        ....
```

I'm expecting to see a list of functions and doc comments in the eDoc output. But, no show.

I've scoured eDoc documentation, looked for examples and tutorials on the web, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Can anyone help?

Many thanks,

LRP

Comment: No need for the extra spaces/lines. You can simply mark part of your text as "code" using the toolbar on the top. This will output the section as pre-formatted. Fixed for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you called edoc correctly, based on your example I would expect to see the outline of your module along with the function names but not the documentation for each function.

Just above each exported function you will need to add a `@spec` tag and/or a `-spec` tag along with a `@doc` tag. You can see these explained [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/edoc/users_guide.html) and [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html). If you have (or are targeting) a recent version of erlang (>14B02?) edoc will read `-spec` information, otherwise you'll need to use `@spec`.

For example:

```
%% @spec item_types() -> list()
%% @doc Return a list of reserved item types.
item_types() ->
```

or

```
-spec item_types() -> list().
%% @doc Return a list of reserved item types.
item_types() ->
```

Note the `.` at the end of the `-spec`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, only exported functions show up in the generated documentation (unless you pass the option 'private' to EDoc, telling it to show all non-exported functions as well). So if you don't have a declaration like:

```
  -export([item_types/0]).
```

in your module, the function will not be shown.

Second, you must begin the comment above the function declaration with @doc, as in:

```
  %% @doc Return a list of reserved item types
  item_types() ->
```

A comment without an @-tag is just a comment, and is ignored by EDoc.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/edoc/chapter.html#Introduction):

> A tag must be the first thing on a comment line, except for leading '%' characters and whitespace.

Could this be the reason?